# To search a specific folder in Google Drive?

Tags: search, google-drive

I know this [How do I search within a specific folder in Google Drive/Docs?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/vEPW91FtIP8) but they have not implemented it yet in Google drive. 
Typing `diabetes folder:turnerwhite` gives me, for instance, nothing.

The current option is to type `diabetes turnerwhite` but assume you are referencing turnerwhite in many other contexes and using it much elsewhere, complicating the issue.

How can you search a specific folder in Google Drive?